# How to count rows with specific ID Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i have a table with 10 rows in total where 6 have `ID 1` and 4 have `ID 2` i want to count only the rows with `ID 1` but my code counts all of them in total. This is my code:

```
$clientOrder = clientHasOrder::where('order_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $rowCount = $clientOrder->count();
        dd($rowCount);
```

If the code worked correct i should get 6 rows with specific `$id` but this code gives 10 rows that are total in the table.

If i do `dd(clientHasOrder::all());` i get:

[image: Result]

This is the result in details as you can see i get the 10 results but i need only 6 rows with specific ID

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1367 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:121
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1369 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 1
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 1
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    1 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1370 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 2
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 2
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    2 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1371 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 3
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 3
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    3 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1372 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 4
        "amount" => "40"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "36"
        "product_id" => 4
        "amount" => "40"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    4 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1373 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 7
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 7
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    5 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1374 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 8
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 8
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    6 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1375 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 9
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 9
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    7 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1376 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 10
        "amount" => "40"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "37"
        "product_id" => 10
        "amount" => "40"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    8 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1377 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 1
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 1
        "amount" => "10"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
    9 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1378 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 7
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 7
        "amount" => "20"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    10 => App\Models\clientHasOrder {#1379 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "client_has_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 9
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▼
        "order_id" => "38"
        "product_id" => 9
        "amount" => "30"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:3 [▼
        0 => "order_id"
        1 => "product_id"
        2 => "amount"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Comment: You are doing a `->firstOrFail()` which will give you the first entry or fail. You should use `->get();`

Comment: Explain this ***i have a table with 10 rows in total where 6 have ID 1 and 4 have ID 2 i want to count only the rows with ID 1 but my code counts all of them in total. This is my code:***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke count directly on the query, like this:

```
$clientOrder = clientHasOrder::where('order_id', $id)->count();

dd($clientOrder);
```

And that will show the correct amount, you do not need to firstOrFail, because if the results are empty, it will show `0 count`.

Comment: i tried this and this gives me only total of rows which for me is 10, i want to count rows with `ID` 6 only

Comment: The query above is 100% correct, what you might be running to is problems with your Model Name, or your actual data, you need to provide more data and information to diagnose why your model is returning all data instead of specific data. start by doing `dd(clientHasOrder::all());` and post the results in your question by editing your question. Also I really recommend that you change your model name, to something like "ClientOrder"

Comment: i edited my post and added the result

Comment: please expand your items, and post the code not an image, I will edit and format it for you if you don't know how to do it :)

Comment: i posted it as code expanded.

Comment: im new to laravalel so im trying to learn the commands from documentation, i have used fillable  but guarded 0 idea what it is where can i find it in the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251513/discussion-between-kgg-and-laracoder).

Comment: Join the chat room, I will help you fix the way you are doing things :)

Comment: this table has only values from other tables like client, products and orders

Comment: sorry for bothering again just one question when it comes to get values from the table `order_product` like the `amount` or to delete it i can not use the model `clientHasOrder` because gives me error that the database doesnt have table called `client_has_order` . How can i fix this so that model can be used again?

Comment: Join the chat room again, I will show you

Comment: @KGG what happned? Illigel voting? :/